# DAX comparison operations do not support values of type integer with text

Tags: powerbi

Trying to get the Total number of STPs from a merge file. Have checked all the columns and did not see any problem with the formatting. Please help. Given the measure below.

```
Total STPs = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER('STP Conv merge', 'STP Conv merge'[S.I.P Input]<>"YES" && 'STP Conv merge'[year]=2022 & 'STP Conv merge'[Tolling] = "YES" && 'STP Conv merge'[Planning Status] = "IMP" && 'STP Conv merge'[Exclude] = "NO")))
```

Comment: Try to format your code to make it easier for other to read - see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting (looks like `lang-dax` should work for you)

Answer (score 0):

While trying to moderate this question, I ran into SO's super fun edit queue never being empty - I was attempting to reformat your code to make it readable, and may have found your bug:

```dax
Total STPs = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER('STP Conv merge', 
        'STP Conv merge'[S.I.P Input]<>"YES" &&
        'STP Conv merge'[year]=2022 &                  <- this?
        'STP Conv merge'[Tolling] = "YES" && 
        'STP Conv merge'[Planning Status] = "IMP" && 
        'STP Conv merge'[Exclude] = "NO")))
```